# function such that the sum of previous f(x) is smaller than f(x)

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Just out of curiosity: is there a function $f$, such that

$ \forall x, \sum_{x'<x} f(x') < f(x) $

sum or integral...

Comment: Is the sum over  $x'$ in the natural  numbers, or what?

Comment: anything, could be also complex

Comment: It doesn't make much sense for complex numbers, as they are not ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_{-\infty}^xe^{2t}\,dt=e^{2x}/2.$

Answer (score 0):

Set $f(x)=2^x$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i=2^n-1<2^n=f(n)$$